# how do i exctract the acres burned within a variable

Tags: sas

hi i need help with extracting the acres burned in a sas file named wildfire_narrative. the varriables within the file are episdoe_id,episode_narrative, event_id, event_narrative. the acres burned are within the variable episode_narrative. episode_narrative contains at least a paragraph of text string and within the text string is the acres burned.

EXAMPLE: Dry Santa winds caused a discarded cigarette butt in the median of Interstate 8 to grow into a 10,353 acre brush fire. Resources used to fight the fire cost over $8 million and involved 2000 fire fighters, nine helicopters, and nine air tankers. Property damaged or destroyed in the fire consisted of 15 single family homes, 65 outbuildings, 15 trailers, and 164 motor vehicles. Several livestock were burned and later euthanasized. thank you.

```
data acres;
set 'C:\Users\scott\Downloads\Wildfire_narrative.sas7bdat';
acresBurned = scan(episode_narrative, findw("acre",0-8,' ')-1, ",");  
run;
```

Comment: Will there ever be cases of multiple words of acre in the text? You will need to include more sample text, as its likely more complicated than a single sample would reflect.  Either way, you likely will need a regular expression. `SCAN` works when you have specific delimiters, which is not your case.

Comment: the word acre is only reference once in each episode_narrative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this in prxchange. This is done by doing by using regular expression by replacing everything else and keep the number in front of acre. by below code, which basically capture various groups and replaces everything with number in front of acre.

```
 acres=input(prxchange('s/(.+?)([0-9\,]+)(?=\s?\-?acre)(.+)/$2/i',-1, 
 acresBurned),comma10.)
```

Brief explanation of above code.

(.+?) is first captured group, which goes till number space followed by word acre

([0-9\,]+) is second capture group with number

(?=\s?-?acre)   is third capture group this is look ahead reference which makes sure there is word acre in front of number followed by space or -

(.+) is fourth capture  group which goes till the end of the sentence.

/$2/ replaces everything with second capture group and input function is used to change the value to a number

> 

```
data have ;
length acresBurned $500.;
acresBurned = "Dry Santa winds caused a discarded cigarette butt in the median 
of    8 to grow into a 10,353 acre brush fire. Resources used to fight the 
fire cost over $8 million and involved 2000 fire fighters, nine helicopters, a 
and nine air tankers. Property damaged or destroyed in the fire consisted of 
15 single family homes, 65 outbuildings, 15 trailers, and 164 motor vehicles. 
Several livestock were burned and later euthanasized";
output;
acresBurned = "Dry Santa winds caused a discarded cigarette butt in the    
median 
of Interstate 8 to grow into a 100,353-acre brush fire. Resources used
to  fight 
the fire cost over $8 million and involved 2000 fire fighters, nine 
helicopters, and nine air tankers. Property damaged or destroyed in the   
fire consisted of 15 single family homes, 65 outbuildings, 15 trailers, and 
164 motor vehicles. Several livestock were burned and later  
euthanasized";    
output;
run;

data have1;
set have;
acres=input(prxchange('s/(.+?)([0-9\,]+)(?=\s?\-?acre)(.+)/$2/i',-1, 
acresBurned),comma10.);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! however I noticed that some values did not appear due to a deliminator '-'. how would I account for the '-' for example: 800-acre.

Comment: would a compression function fix that?

Comment: also is it possible to add another column that also contains the word acre(s)?